# In proc sql when using SELECT * and GROUP BY, the result is not collapsed

Tags: sql, sas

When using the asterisk in combination with sum and group, the duplicates are not removed as I expect (and as it works in for example mysql):

```
col1 | country 
-----------------
5    | sweden  
20   | sweden  
30   | denmark 

select *, sum(col1) as s from table
group by country
```

the data returned is:

```
col1 | country | s
--------------------
5    | sweden  | 25
20   | sweden  | 25
30   | denmark | 30
```

instead of what I expected:

```
col1 | country | s
------------------------
5    | sweden  | 25
30   | denmark | 30
```

If I don't use asterisk (*), the data returned is as I expect it to be.

```
SELECT country, sum(col1) as s from table
```

Comment: Why would you expect `10` for `col1` output? How, when you `sum(col1)` is the output `25` and not `50`. What are you expectations for columns that are not either aggregated by a function like `sum()` or in your `GROUP BY` clause? It must show that data somehow if the column appears in your `SELECT` either explicitly named or when using `*`. Maybe it would be helpful if you shared sample data from this table and your desired results (with correct calculations performed) so that we can help write the SQL you need.

Comment: oups, my error. i didn't mean 10 in col1, i fix.

Comment: You might want to consider `Proc UNIVARIATE`, `FREQ` or `MEANS` if you want to compute aggregate results for lots of different numeric measures in lots of different class combinations.

Comment: Why do you expect to get 5 for col1? Why not 20?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, SAS does not collapse WHEN you have variables in the statement that are not in the GROUP BY statement. 
There will be a note to that effect in the log, about your data being merged.

If you want just the variables, you'll have to list them unfortunately, but since you have to list them in GROUP BY it's not extra work per se.

Different SQL implementations handle things differently, this is one way that SAS is different. It's handy when you do want to merge a summary stat back with the main data set though.

If you don't want this behaviour add the NOREMERGE option to your PROC SQL - but it throws an error, it still doesn't work the way you want. 
[See the documentation for the reference](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p12ohgh32ffm6un13s7l2d5p9c8y.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p01454eymsw9d4n1w381xc8dy8uw)

Comment: But the dataset have hundreds of columns and I do not mean to group by them (they contain the same data on all rows in the relevant groups...). But if i understand you correctly I don't have an option to naming the columns, and to do it twice…

Comment: One approach is to use a %varlist(data=) macro which will allow you to pass the name of a dataset, and will return a comma delimited list of the variables in the dataset, so that you don't have to type the long list of variables.

Comment: If they contain the exact same data add `distinct` and that will solve your issues, however, in your example you do not have the exact same values, specifically, col1 changes across rows so it's not unique. You can use the `FEEDBACK` option in proc sql to get SAS to generate the list of variables so you don't have to type them out. Add that to your PROC SQL and check the log.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `SELECT *`, ever.  It's bad practice, risky, unsustainable...  Read about it.

What flavor of SQL?

Your first query shouldn't work.  You're basically saying...

```
select col1
, country
, sum(col1) as s
from table
group by country
```

...which will return an error:

`Column 'table.col1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

```
SELECT country, sum(col1) as s from table
```

...also should not work:

`Column 'table.country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Given your expected output, I suspect what you are looking for is...

```
select min(col1) as col1
, country
, sum(col1) as s
from table
group by country
```

Comment: Proc sql, as stated in title. This is actually part of cleaning up and normalizing a huge dataset, it's not meant as sql to be used in production. It's only run once in the purpose of generating the dataset.